# Having issues with flattening some nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some data like showed below, I wanted to get the sum of all the positive, negative and neutral for the type student, so I did a d3.nest method where I used the key as student, and returned the sum of the value mentioned.

```
{Type: student, positive: 2, negative: 1, neutral:0}, {Type: student, positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0}, {Type: student, positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0}, {Type: student, positive: 1, negative: 2, neutral:0}
```

This is the result of that d3.nest, in the .rollup return statement i specified the value name like this `positive: d3.sum(d,function(f){ return f.positive;})` etc. Below is the result.

```
`key: "student"
     value: {positive: 5, negative: 5, neutral: 0}`
```

However, to plot a radar graph I need to flatten the data so it is one level like below, but i cannot figure out how to do it. I tried doing it like the code shown below but kept getting errors please could you help.

```
{student: student, positive:5, negative:5, neutral:0}
```

I have tried this forEach loop and it did not work

```
var flatData = []
            subStudent.forEach(function(sub){
                sub.value(function(subval){
                    flatData.push({
                        level: sub.key,
                        value: subval.value
                    });
                });
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(flatData))
```

Comment: Please post a proper input data sample

Comment: @AyushGupta I have added the sample data

Comment: Can you edit your input data and output data accordingly @AyushGupta ? I felt it bit confusing.

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar not my question mate,

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar I have edited the question above hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably don't really need `d3.nest()`, unless you have a reason in mind?

You can do it with reduce (but I will also include the `d3.nest()` example below too):

```js
const input = [
  {Type: 'student', positive: 2, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 2, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 2, negative: 0, neutral:1},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0}
];

const output = Object.values(input.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  
  if (!aggObj.hasOwnProperty(item.Type)) aggObj[item.Type] = item;
  else {
    for (let key in item){
      if (key != "Type") aggObj[item.Type][key] += item[key];
    } 
  }
  return aggObj
}, {}))

console.log(output)
```

Input:

```js
[
  { Type: 'student', positive: 2, negative: 1, neutral:0 },
  { Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0 },
  { Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0 },
  { Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 2, neutral:0 },
  { Type: 'other',   positive: 2, negative: 0, neutral:1 },
  { Type: 'other',   positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0 },
  { Type: 'other',   positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0 }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  { Type: "student", positive: 5, negative: 5, neutral: 0 },
  { Type: "other",   positive: 4, negative: 2, neutral: 1 }
]
```

**If you need/want `d3.nest()` you can do this (same input & output):**

```js
const input = [
  {Type: 'student', positive: 2, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'student', positive: 1, negative: 2, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 2, negative: 0, neutral:1},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0},
  {Type: 'other', positive: 1, negative: 1, neutral:0}
];

const nested = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.Type)
  .rollup(d => ({
    positive: d3.sum(d, f => f.positive),
    negative: d3.sum(d, f => f.negative),
    neutral: d3.sum(d, f => f.neutral),
  }))  
  .entries(input)
  
const output = nested.map(item => {
  //console.log(item)
  return {Type: item.key, ...item.value}
})

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think that nested might be my best way potentially, as I have a few more values I want to specify I just have those three as example to get an idea, thank you I will mark it as the answer if I get a solution